# What should I set the $DISPLAY environmental variable to?

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, centos6, digital-ocean

I'm ssh'ing into a CentOS 6 VPS (from Mac Terminal) and trying to run emacs:

```
emacs ~/.bashrc &
```

At first I get nothing. Then, I try:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Now, when I try emacs again, I get:

```
Display :0 unavailable, simulating -nw
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, 6 people think this is off-topic. To me, it relates to the section of the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) called 'software tools commonly used by programmers'. If this is relevant for a different stack exchange site, I'd certainly appreciate a point in the right direction. Thanks, and I will try to keep it relevant going forward.

Comment: Emacs itself *is* 100% on-topic for that reason, but this isn't really an Emacs question (assuming that Emacs is not the only X application for which you are having DISPLAY problems), so the question is possibly better suited for the SuperUser site, or the Unix stackexchange site.

Comment: Got it; I posted it on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/726677/how-can-i-see-on-my-local-display-emacs-and-other-graphical-apps-running-on). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is it possible to transfer an existing question as a whole to another site? That would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question whether you actually have an X server set up on your Mac, so I’ll explain that first.

In order to use Emacs in graphical rather than terminal mode, you need an “X Server.” The X Window System is a standard and protocol which allows programs to draw on a display by sending messages over a communications channel, either locally or over a network (TCP). The machine with the display/keyboard/mouse runs the X server; programs such as Emacs which want to draw on the display are called X clients.

OS X does not come with an X server. You can get one from here: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/. Apple used to include one, but they dropped it recently.

Once you have X working on your Mac, you can then run Emacs on your VPS and have it display on the Mac. You could set the DISPLAY variable (and adjust your firewall etc.) to have Emacs connect directly to your X server over the Internet, but this is a bad idea: the X protocol is insecure, and you don't want to expose that to the Internet. Instead, you can use SSH “X forwarding.” *ssh -X* is a specialized form of *ssh -R*: it sets up a TCP port listening on the loopback of the remote host, and sets the DISPLAY variable when you log in to point to this proxy. X clients on the remote side then transparently connect to your local X server, tunneled over the SSH connection.

Because of the network delay, it may take a few seconds for remote X clients to appear on your display. Emacs takes a particularly long time to appear, though I find that once it does ongoing operation is usually pretty smooth.

> I installed xquartz and now get: X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

Please post the output of your SSH session with *ssh -vv*, when you try this. Do you have the *xauth* program installed on the VPS? *sshd* uses that to establish a separate X authentication token (“MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE”) on the server side. It intercepts the initial X protocol authentication message and substitutes the remote (“spoofed”) token; this avoids exposing your local token on the remote host.

You might also try *ssh -Y* instead of *ssh -X*.

> I should add that echo $DISPLAY (in Terminal, before I ssh into the VPS), now gives me this: /tmp/launch-ZMvHpM/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

That’s normal. This is general mechanism OS X uses to launch services on demand; this is set by *launchd* (I believe), and it automatically starts the X server when you run your first X client.

Comment: Thank you Richard E. Silverman. Very helpful overview. I installed xquartz and now get: X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0 ... I checked the sshd_config file per instructions [here](http://oroborosx.sourceforge.net/remotex.html) and X11Forwarding Yes is there (and not commented out). I also successfully launched xterm from terminal and an X11 window popped up. What might I be missing? I should add that echo $DISPLAY (in Terminal, before I ssh into the VPS), now gives me this: /tmp/launch-ZMvHpM/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

Comment: Richatd, I've posted the output of -vv [here](http://superuser.com/questions/726677/how-can-i-see-on-my-local-display-emacs-and-other-graphical-apps-running-on) (where hopefully the post will not be considered off-topic).

Comment: Richard, installing xauth worked. I can now view emacs on my local host.

Comment: However, the font issue is a problem I haven't figured out how to get around yet... Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin' -- full description of the issue available at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/726677/how-can-i-see-on-my-local-display-emacs-and-other-graphical-apps-running-on).

Comment: Solved the font issue [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1372).

Answer (score 0):

Emacs tries to open a window in the remote machine, without an *X Windows* server running.

Try to enable X forwarding to your local machine with `ssh -X`, or run emacs there in console mode with `emacs -nw` (no windows).

Comment: Running emacs -nw gets emacs running in the current terminal (which is certainly better than nothing—thanks!), but I want to be able to launch it in the background. I tried adding -X to my ssh command when logging into the VPS but I get nothing.